# How to ignore jQuery breakpoints when debugging in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, debugging, google-chrome

Whenever I try to debug my website, it stops many times in the jQuery .js file, even if there are no breakpoints there. This is very annoying, as I only want to debug where I have put breakpoints in my code.

How can i make chrome ignore the jQuery core file when debugging, and only focus on the places where I have put a breakpoint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When debuggin using Chrome the only reason the debugger stops inside the jQuery files is if you use <kbd>F11</kbd> (step-in) while debugging instead of <kbd>F8</kbd> (pause/continue execution) or if an error was encountered and you have `pause on errors` enabled.

Off course any `debugger;` lines will also force the execution to halt.

To ignore errors there is a little circle icon in the `Sources` tab  on the bottom which can be clicked into 3 states.

- Gray State = Don't Pause on Exceptions
- Blue State = Pause on all exceptions
- Purple State = Paus only on uncaught exceptions

See image below regarding the icon I'm refering to, click it for the different states.

Also, on the right of the image you can see different sections like: `DOM Breakpoints` and `XHR Breakpoints`, etc. Check those have no breakpoints either, just-in case.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Adjusting the little pause icon in the bottom left and setting it to "Dont pause on exceptions" fixed it. Thanks alot. This saves me a lot of time :)

Comment: You may want to leave that on and use blackboxing instead, see my answer below

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're looking for a recent developer feature called "black boxing". The feature will allow debuggers to essentially *step through* library code while step debugging.

You can read more about it here: http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/ignoring-library-code-while-debugging-in-chrome/

Answer (score 4):

Blackboxing (ignoring exceptions in certain files) is now natively supported in google chrome.

`development tools > settings > Manage framework blackboxing`

And even easier, just right click in the file and say `Blackbox this script`

Firefox has auto-blackboxing of minified JS files even!

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan's answer is the most useful and works well so I can debug my own code and not jquery's. But the location of this setting has changed since he wrote it. To find it now:

- open DevTools (ctrl-shift-j)
- hit the settings icon (top right)
- choose Ignore List from the settings sections on the left
- make sure Enable Ignore Listing is checked
- Under custom exclusion rules click Add pattern and add jquery* (or however your jquery installation is name)